Elasticsearch bulk API: how do I know which error "belongs" to which document
I want to use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html
with raise_on_error=False.
When some of the documents given to the bulk operation succeed and some do not how can I lik the errors to the data that I put in as the input?
I intend to use this via python elasticsearch library.

In the same page as the one you sent in your question there is an example bulk operation where you can see an example request and response.
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }

In this example (taken from the link above) there are 4 operations (index, delete, create, update).
Now the result (again taken from the link above)
{
    "took":30,
    "errors":false,
    "items":[
        {"index":{"_index":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"status":201,"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1}},
        {"delete":{"_index":"test","_id":"2","_version":1,"result":"not_found","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"status":404,"_seq_no":1,"_primary_term":2}},
        {"create":{"_index":"test","_id":"3","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"status":201,"_seq_no":2,"_primary_term":3}},
        {"update":{"_index":"test","_id":"1","_version":2,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"status":200,"_seq_no":3,"_primary_term":4}}
    ]
}

shows that each operation in the bulk document will have a corresponding ordered result.
So, for example, in the bulk document the delete operation comes second and therefore in the items array of the response it is also placed second (at index 1). In the above example, erroneous operations will have a status other than 200-299. But in the above example, the delete failed softly and therefore the errors field is false.
If the failure qualified as a hard fail then the errors field would be true. One such example of a hard fail would be to try and delete a document from a nonexistent index. In that case, you would get the following instead.
{
    "took":30,
    "errors":true,
    "items":[
        ...
        {"delete":{"_index":"idx","_type":"doc","_id":"2","status":404,"error":{ "type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type": "index_expression","resource.id":"idx","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"idx"}}}
        ...
    ]
}

In any case the order of the items in the response will much that of the operations in the bulk document.
